# Change tabula separator to another character

Tags: python, csv, spreadsheet, tabula

I need to capture some data from a pdf and input into an excel file, but to create a macro to organize the cells I need a character other than "**,**". Because some value datas need the "," for cents. Any ideas ? (A character like "/" or "-" would solve the problem)

When i convert my pdf to csv, all the data are located into one cell, that's why i need to use a macro.
[How my data is organized into excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iij1o.png)

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabula import convert_into
convert_into("B.pdf", "BBBBB.csv", output_format="csv", pages=1,coding = 'latin-1',stream=True, guess = False ,
         area = (306.9,253,379,570),
         columns = (347,399.1,443.4,481.6,514.3,543.5,572))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep using `convert_into` you can set `output_format="tsv"`, which converts table with tab delimited format. https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.wrapper.convert_into
Other than that, you can convert to DataFrame with `read_csv` then use `df.to_csv` with setting delimiter.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU! the translate to tsv has worked a lot

Answer (score 0):

The "," inside the data values are correctly escaped inside `" "` markers and will just work. What is wrong is your Excel which is not using the `,` as the field delimiter. IIRC, you can overcome this on Excel's side by using `File->import` instead of just trying to open the CSV file. This way Excel will prompt you for the CSV parameters.

Otherwise, the Python CSV writter parameter to change the delimiter character is exactly "delimiter" -

Unfortunateely Tabula-py is just a wrapper around tabula-java called via an external process, and that accept no option to change the delimiter character. Otherwise, it would be a matter of adding a `delimiter=...` 
 parameter on your call.

As it is, however, the easiest way to go seem to be to re-convert your CSV file generated on the Java side to one with ";" delimiters after the data is extracted:

(The example has a quite complete wrapper function, but the conversion takes place at just four lines of code at the end)

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabula import convert_into


def convert(input_file, output_file, encoding="latin1", area=None, columns=None, delimiter=";"):
    if area is None:
        area = (306.9, 253, 379, 570)
    if columns is None:
        columns = (347, 399.1, 443.4, 481.6, 514.3, 543.5, 572)

    if delimiter != ",":
        final_output = Path(output_file)
        # temporary name
        output_file = final_output.parent / (final_output.stem + "_tmp" + final_output.suffix)

    # perform the actual data extraction and CSV output
    convert_into(
        input_file,
        output_file,
        output_format="csv",
        pages=1,
        coding="latin-1",
        stream=True,
        guess=False,
        area=area,
        columns=columns,
    )

    if delimiter != ",":
        # if needed, convert the CSV file to use the required delimiters:
        try:
            with open(output_file) as tabula_csv, open(final_output) as final_csv:
                reader = csv.reader(tabula_csv)
                writer = csv.writer(final_csv, delimiter=delimiter)
                writer.writerows(reader)
        else:

            # if everything was ok on conversion, remove temporary file:
            output_file.unlink()
```

Comment: I tried to open with excel the file, and the "," persist, i think its the delimiter that tabula's uses. And the code didn't work :/

Comment: Sorry for that - I went to check the docs, and in fact it does not work - I will add  to the answer an example of the CSV conversion on teh Python side now.